# Deploying a simple report with a shared dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I've created a new SSRS project, and added a shared data source. When I run the project, I get the expected result succesfully.

However, when I try to deploy the report I get:

> Error: Cannot deploy the report because the shared data source '/Data Sources/DataSource1' that the report references does not exist on the report server.

I'm guessing I am missing something very simple and critical because I am a complete beginner.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the dataset you are using exist on the report server?

Comment: @bluefeet thank you for your response. yes the data set is on the same server as the project

Comment: You'll have to deploy the shared data source before deploying the report. Did you do that?

Comment: @brian that did the trick! thanks so much!! you can make that into an answer! can you also please show me how to turn a PIVOT query into an SSRS project?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. First, deploy the data source:

   [image]
2. Then, deploy any necessary shared datasets:

   [image]
3. Now, you'll be able to deploy or run your report.

Answer (score 1):

### If trying to deploy dataset but still getting this error...

I have discovered that if you change the name of the shared data source after you have already created a corresponding shared dataset, then the "DataSourceReference" property in the dataset does not change accordingly, is not be editable via the wizard, and it will throw this misleading error.

On the shared **dataset**, right-click and go to "Open With..." --> "XML (Text) Editor".

There you will see the raw configuration file. Make sure the `<DataSourceReference>` node has the proper value...

[image: XML sample]

Answer (score 0):

Scenario: You've decided to use a Shared Dataset on your report but you haven't used it. Make sure to select the proper datasets for this issue.

Answer with steps:
On the Report Data tab on your SSDT double click the Datasets(not the one with the folder sign). It'll open the Dataset Properties.
- when the Dataset properties is open make sure to select a Dataset that your report is suppose to use.
-press OK.
-Solved[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUZhJ.png)